# How do you specify the type of a &rest argument in Common Lisp/SBCL?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

### Problem

Say I have code like this:

```
(deftype fruit () '(member :apple :orange :pear))

(declaim (ftype (function (&rest fruit)) place-order))
(defun place-order (&rest selections)
  (dolist (s selections)
    (format t "Ordering ~S~%" s)))
```

and later, in the same package, I make a call like this:

```
(place-order :orange :apple :bacon)
```

SBCL accepts this code and runs it without issue. But I would like it to fail due to `:bacon` not being a `fruit` type (i.e. `(typep :bacon 'fruit) => NIL`).

### Hacky workaround

This code behaves the way I want:

```
(deftype fruit () '(member :apple :orange :pear))

(declaim (ftype (function (&optional fruit fruit fruit)) place-order-hack))
(defun place-order-hack (&optional choice-a choice-b choice-c)
  (dolist (s (remove-if 'null (list choice-a choice-b choice-c)))
    (format t "Ordering ~S~%" s)))

(place-order-hack :orange :apple :bacon)
```

This gives me this nice error:

```
Unhandled TYPE-ERROR in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING
                                  {1001DD0003}>:
  The value
    :BACON
  is not of type
    (MEMBER :APPLE :ORANGE :PEAR NIL)
  when binding CHOICE-C
```

...but using optional arguments as a substitute for a `&rest` argument feels... wrong.

Is there any way I can get an error like this using a `&rest` parameter?

Answer (score 4):

Your type declaration is correct: you are specifying that every element of the rest list should be a `fruit`.   However SBCL is not checking the declaration, probably because doing so is expensive?

As a note: it is never safe to assume that type declarations will be checked in portable code.  SBCL does check them (or in fact, as is clear here, some of them) under common optimization settings, but other implementations do not.  If you want type checks which you *know* happen you should generally write code which checks the types.

A way of making SBCL check the type is to add a declaration where you're looking at a single item:

```
(defun place-order (&rest selections)
  (dolist (s selections)
    (declare (type fruit s))
    (format t "Ordering ~S~%" s)))
```

A way of making the code portably check the types you're after is to check them:

```
(defun place-order (&rest selections)
  (dolist (s selections)
    (declare (type fruit s))
    (check-type s fruit)
    (format t "Ordering ~S~%" s)))
```

Both of these will have the problem that the check may happen too late for you (you don't want any orders to happen).  In that case you probably need something like this:

```
(defun place-order (&rest selections)
  (assert (every (lambda (s)
                   (typep s 'fruit))
                 selections)
      (selections) "not all your fruit are fruit")
  (dolist (s selections)
    (format t "Ordering ~S~%" s)))
```

This will check the types both in SBCL and any other implementation.